# bad argument in gen_tcp recv when split

Tags: erlang, elixir

Hi I´m reading a request where I want to get the path, but when I run this code

```
    {:ok, line} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
    IO.inspect "************************* #{ inspect line} "

    [_server_name, verb, info_path, _version] = String.split(line)
```

Where the inspect looks ok with 4 arguments

```
    {:http_request, :GET, {:abs_path, \"/gg\"}, {1, 1}}
```

The error said:

```
{badarg,[{binary,split,
                 [{http_request,'GET',{abs_path,<<"/gg">>},{1,1}},
                  [<<227,128,128>>,
                   <<226,129,159>>,
                   <<226,128,169>>,
                   <<226,128,168>>,
                   <<226,128,128>>,
                   <<226,128,129>>,
                   <<226,128,130>>,
                   <<226,128,131>>,
                   <<226,128,132>>,
                   <<226,128,133>>,
                   <<226,128,134>>,
                   <<226,128,136>>,
                   <<226,128,137>>,
                   <<226,128,138>>,
                   <<225,154,128>>,
                   <<194,133>>,
                   <<" ">>,<<"\t">>,<<"\n">>,<<"\v">>,<<"\f">>,<<"\r">>],
                  [global,trim_all]],
                 []},
```

I don't know what are all those extra arguments of the line.

If I try just bind the line with every type without the split I receive

```
    [_server_name, verb, info_path, _version] = line


{{badmatch,{http_request,'GET',{abs_path,<<"/gg">>},{1,1}}},
```

Comment: this should work for you: `{_server_name, verb, info_path, _version} = line`, (replacing `[` with `{`)

Comment: jeeez I was so so blind!, thanks!

Comment: Also, note that what you're calling `_server_name` is really the `:http_request` tuple tag. See the [`erlang:decode_packet/3` documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#decode_packet-3) for details on the definition of this tuple.

Comment: Since this error seems to be down to a simple typo `[` vs. `{` etc., vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read the docs of [`:gen_tcp.recv`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#recv-2) correctly, you "should" receive a [`HttpPacket`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#decode_packet-3) back, which in your case seems to be a `HttpRequest`. Since the parsing of the request is handled for you, you "should" be able to simply do:

```
{:ok, line} = :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0)
{_server_name, verb, info_path, _version} = line
```

**Note:** The `HttpRepuest` uses `{...}` curly brackets and not `[...]` brackets.